# I have been told that in an xyz plane.The normal on incident point is given,how do I visualise a normal which is like this

Tags: optics

Suppose I have a ray of light incident on a plane mirror in the general form of $$ai+bj-ck$$. I have a normal that is along $$\frac{i+j}{√2}$$. The question asks me to find the unit vector but that is not what I'm asking. My question is ,where should I visualise a vector like this,if it was like, $$\frac{i+j}{2}$$ it should have been easier or in a single direction or no fractions,but I'm finding it hard to visualise $$\frac{i+j}{√2}$$. On a graph or a diagram, where would this lie?
(i ,j,and k are unit vectors)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but :$$\frac{\hat i  + \hat j }{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \hat i + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \hat j$$

[image]

Comment: Does this imply the angles here are 45°.

Comment: If the above is the normal vector, then the normal vector of the surface, has an angle in radians of $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4} $ relative to the x axis

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: https://ibb.co/gwQpjtj ,I hope based on what is given,this is a correct representation @jensen paull